# Change size of layout in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm making a layout for a `CardView`, and I can't get the layout itself to be the right size. The `LinearLayout` is the right size, but Android Studio still shows the full screen size. Is this a coding error or an Android Studio bug?
My code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

My xml preview is [image: xml preview]

The `LinearLayout` for the card view is not showing at all after I used `tools:showIn`

Comment: Is the problem just in the Android Studio layout preview? You could perhaps use the `tools:showIn` attribute to change how the preview is drawn.

Comment: it could be. I'll try that

Comment: Add screenshot of your xml preview too.

Comment: I just tried the `tools:showIn` and it is saying "The surrounding layout (@layout/new_ui_layout) did not actually include this layout. Remove tools:showIn=... from the root tag."

Comment: is this a problem only in the editor, or also on runtime?

Comment: Its only in the editor, but it is extremely bothersome

Answer (score 0):

Just change a `orientation` of `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The layout I am making uses a horizontal LinearLayout